# How to set a dataframe to contain result simply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

`query` and `get_fundamentals` are some APP's `api`,it does not matter to point out which `api` it is.
Below is my snippet to use dataframe.

```
code = "some"
caldate = [datetime.date(2003, 12, 31),datetime.date(2004, 12, 31),
           datetime.date(2005, 12, 31), datetime.date(2006, 12, 31)]
for curdate in caldate:
    q = query(valuation.market_cap).filter(valuation.code == code)
    y = get_fundamentals(q,date=curdate)
    print(y)
```

The output is as below:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap]
Index: []
   market_cap
0    215.2808
   market_cap
0    828.9395
```

I expect to create a dataframe to contain all output.

```
container
   market_cap
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    215.2808
3    828.9395

type(container)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I have a try(failure) with concat:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['market_cap'])
for curdate in caldate:
    q = query(valuation.market_cap).filter(valuation.code == code)
    y = get_fundamentals(q,date=curdate)
    pd.concat([result,y],axis = 0)
```

The output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap, market_cap]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap, market_cap]
Index: []
   market_cap  market_cap
0         NaN    215.2808
   market_cap  market_cap
0         NaN    828.9395
>>> result
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap]
Index: []
```

Another try(failure):

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['market_cap'])
for curdate in caldate:
    q = query(valuation.market_cap).filter(valuation.code == code)
    y = get_fundamentals(q,date=curdate)
    result = result.append(y)
```

Print result to see what i get:

```
result
   market_cap
0    215.2808
0    828.9395
```

The desired result:

```
   market_cap
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    215.2808
3    828.9395
```

The first two empty was lost.

Another try(success):set a list to add output ,then assign it to a dataframe.

```
result = []
for curdate in caldate:
    q = query(valuation.market_cap).filter(valuation.code == code)
    y = get_fundamentals(q,date=curdate)['market_cap']
    if y.empty:
        result.append(numpy.nan)
    else:
        result.append(y[0])

container = pd.DataFrame()
container['market_cap'] = result
```

Maybe there is a more simple and more pythonic way to achieve my expectation.

@YOLO,print(result) according to your code.

```
result
                                        market_cap
0  Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap]
Index: []
1  Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap]
Index: []
2                         market_cap
0    215.2808
3                         market_cap
0    828.9395
```

Show every element in result.

```
>>> result["market_cap"][0]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap]
Index: []
>>> result["market_cap"][1]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [market_cap]
Index: []
>>> result["market_cap"][2]
   market_cap
0    215.2808
>>> result["market_cap"][3]
   market_cap
0    828.9395
```

My expectation:

```
>>> result["market_cap"][0]
nan
>>> result["market_cap"][1]
nan
>>> result["market_cap"][2]
215.2808
>>> result["market_cap"][3]
828.9395
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Something similar to your last step should work:

```
result = [] 
for curdate in caldate:
    q = query(valuation.market_cap).filter(valuation.code == code)
    y = get_fundamentals(q,date=curdate) # assuming this returns a NaN or some numeric
    result.append(y)

result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['market_cap'])
```